# Who coined the term Orthonormal?

Tags: math-history, orthonormal, convention

Does anyone know who coined the term orthonormal to refer to a basis that is orthogonal and normal.

In such a poorly named mathematical world (looking at you conditionally convergent series) I think we should shine more light on good naming, such as orthonormal. Some may argue that it can be confused with orthogonal, but to that I say just be better. Its concise, it sounds nice, and it is very very intuitive.

So if anyone knows the mathematician who popularized the term I would be forever greatful, all you get when you look it up is the Gram-Schmidt process (no disrespect to my boys Gram and Schmidt tho, they're G's fr)

Thank you

Comment: My biggest gripe here is that a (real) matrix is called orthogonal iff it has orthonormal columns. That's just stupid.

Comment: Good question, but you probably get better answers from https://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

The earliest attestation I've found so far (not a coinage) is in Salomon Bochner, "Additive set functions on groups", Annals of Mathematics, Oct., 1939, Second Series, Vol. 40, No. 4 (Oct., 1939), pp. 769-799. Bochner uses the word "orthonormal" seven times, without defining it, which means that the editor and intended readers were already familiar with it. The first usage is, "Let $C$ be an arbitrary module and $\{ \varphi_{\alpha}(x) \}$ an arbitrary (not necessarily countable) orthonormal system of elements from $C$ [12]." Reference 12 is a 1936 paper of van Kampen that does not contain the word "orthonormal". If I had to guess, I'd guess that the term was perhaps used informally throughout the mid-1930s, too informal in '36 for van Kampen to use it, but respectable by '39. That might be way off, though.

Comment: Stone's 1932 _Linear transformations in Hilbert space_, p.193 uses the term.